# How to get values from an XML file matching XPath query in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm wondering whether there is a way using C# which enables me to return all the inner values within an XML file matching a given XPath query.

Let's suppose that we have the following Xml file named exampleWithFruits.xml:

```
<fruits>
   <bananas>
      <banana id="1" color="yellow" price="0.5" />
      <banana id="2" color="yellow" price="0.4" />
      <banana id="3" color="yellow" price="0.6" />
   </bananas>
   <apples>
      <apple id="1" color="red" price="0.5" />
      <apple id="2" color="red" price="0.4" />
      <apple id="3" color="green" price="0.6" />
      <apple id="4" color="yellow" price="0.4" />
   </apples>
   <oranges>
      <orange id="1" color="orange" price="0.5" />
      <orange id="2" color="orange" price="0.5" />
   </oranges>
</fruits>
```

Something like following below:

```
string xmlFilePath = "exampleWithFruits.xml";
string xPathQuery = "//fruits/apples//@color"
string[] matchingValues = interestingFunction(xmlFilePath, xPathQuery);
//for instance we would get something like : matchingValues = {red, red, green, yellow}
```

To sum up, I would like to know how to create a function such as **interestingFunction**

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathEvaluate`.

E.g.

```
string xmlFilePath = "exampleWithFruits.xml";
string xPathQuery = "//fruits/apples//@color";

var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
IEnumerable att = (IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate(xPathQuery);
string[] matchingValues = att.Cast<XAttribute>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Or if you prefer XmlDocument:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
string[] matchingValues = doc.SelectNodes(xPathQuery).Cast<XmlAttribute>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Where can I find System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathEvaluate?

Comment: @Pamplemousse Add a reference to the assembly System.Xml.Linq.dll

Comment: I'm able to add System.Xml.XPath.Extensions but not System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathEvaluate after adding the System.Xml.Linq.dll assembly reference.

Comment: Alright! I found it on [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb341675.aspx). It is simply: `using System.Xml.XPath;`