# How to update the Page Title in Web Forms from a dynamically populated FormView Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

FormViewTitleHow would you update your page title if you have a tag element inside a ListView or FormView Control (ASP.NET), that will change according to the data you're retrieving. For example the title of a book. The control will retrieve the title after the page is generated. My question is, is there a way to update the Page Title after the page is rendered or somehow pass this information to the Page.Title of the LabelTitle (ID) value?

Please help!.

This is my code simplify

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormViewTitle" 
            Runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="XmlDataSourceTitle"
            AllowPaging="False">
         <ItemTemplate>                        
             <asp:Label ID="LabelTitle" runat="server" Text="">
                <%#Eval("name") %>
              </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:FormView>
     <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSourceTitle" 
               DataFile="BooksTitles.xml"
               TransformFile ="TransformRSS.xslt">                 
     </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

So far I've done this (in the code behind) to access the FormView Control, but is not working:

```
if (FormViewTitle.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)        
{
    Label pt = (Label)FormViewTitle.FindControl("LabelTitle");
    this.Page.Title = pt.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the change event in your code Behind Page class you can try this:

```
Page.Title = "Change Book Title";
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that.  That would be so simple.  Remember that the title is retrieved from a DB or XML File after the page is generated.

Comment: Yes, but when you change the item in the data list you can fire a change event and send the title (or find the title in your class), in that event you can change the Page title, Page.Title=variableBookTitle

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  This imply to access the ListView or FormVew control.  How would you do that ?  Can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is a basic example to accomplish what you want, I create a simple listView that bind to list of Book objects, I create a Button for each item in the ItemTemplate and I send as command name the title of the book, with this title in the code behind I change the Title of the Page, Try it.
**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestListView.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestListView" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Book Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Text='<%# Eval("Title")%>' runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("Title")%>' Text="Select" OnCommand="btnChange_Command" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TestListView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var books = new List<Book>
            {
                new Book {Title = "Book 1"},
                new Book {Title = "Book 2"},
                new Book {Title = "Book 3"}
            };
            ListView1.DataSource = books;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void btnChange_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = e.CommandName;
    }

}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cesar, I really appreciate your effort for trying to help me.  I ran your code and it works great, but there is problem. I am not using any button to fire up this event or command.  Maybe I haven't explain myself clear.  What I'm trying to accomplish is this: Imagine the user is at the home page and want to navigate to another page where the title, image and description of a Book will be display. I could pass some information to the next page (title) and easy get the Page Title, but I am not doing that. The only parameter I am passing to is a productId.

Comment: With the productId, make an XPath search in your Xml File to find the name of the book, you can use this post to guide in the process. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951593/how-to-get-values-from-an-xml-file-matching-xpath-query-in-c-sharp

Comment: Although, you gave me a good idea to modify some things. It will work great if I select to display other books in the same page (calling the same page). But your method is not working when the page is rendered the first time. Does it make sense, what I'm saying. But again, thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Yes it could work for you to show the information of the book in the same page I recommend you to use Ajax for that. The first time is not selected any book so the title is not selected for the Page, but the way if you find this is the answer you could checked it as the answer.