# C# reading values of elements from an XML tree

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read some values of specific elements in an XML document, such as the values of <main><alpha>, <main><beta><epsilon> and <main><gama><delta>.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<main>
  <alpha>One</alpha>
  <beta>
    <delta>DeltaValueFromBeta</delta>
    <epsilon>EpsilonValueFromBeta</epsilon>
    <phi>PhiValueFromBeta</phi>
  </beta>
  <gamma>
    <delta>DeltaValueFromGamma</delta>
    <epsilon>EpsilonValueFromGamma</epsilon>
    <phi>PhiValueFromGamma</phi>
  </gamma>
</main>
```

I can get the values using code like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Sample.xml");
var quiz = from elements in doc.Elements("main").Elements("beta").Elements("epsilon")
           select elements;

foreach (var item in quiz)
{
  string sValue = (string) item.Value;
  textBox1.AppendText(sValue);
}
```

Is there a more direct way to select the element values I need, without having to use a foreach loop?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in your linq query:

```
var quiz = (from elements in doc.Elements("main").Elements("beta").Elements("epsilon")
       select (string)elements).ToList();
```

It will give you value list.And you can append your text without using foreach:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var values = quiz.Select(x => sb.Append(x));
textBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

Or better way:

```
var text = doc.Descendants("epsilon")
               .Select(x => (string)x)
               .Aggregate((x,y) => x + y);
textBox1.AppendText(text)
```

Comment: Using StringBuilder and AppendText its duplicate. One of them is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you Selman22. I initially tried the code you wrote and I thought I got back a wrong result (in fact it was correct, but I got tired).

Answer (score 2):

XPath is another option for direct access to a node. This reference may assist you.
[How to get values from an XML file matching XPath query in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951593/how-to-get-values-from-an-xml-file-matching-xpath-query-in-c-sharp)

Edit to add to text box without foreach where result = XPath query result collection:

```
textbox1.AppendText(result.Select(x => x.Value));
```

XPath allows for dynamic path building a little easier than LINQ queries.

Comment: +1 i was writing this when i seen your answer pop ^^. Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to begin with XPath requests. It is not exhaustive and does not contain a complete reference but is a good place to start.

Comment: He asked for an optimization of the for loop, not of the from statement. With XPath he'll still get an array of items which needs to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following so you do not have to use a foreach:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = quiz.Select(x => x.Value);
```

Or all in one:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = doc.Elements("main").Elements("beta").Elements("epsilon").Select(x => x.Value);

textBox1.AppendText(values.Aggregate((i, j) => i + j));
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer. I get an error from your sample code "cannot implicitly Ienumerable to List"

Comment: List<string> values = doc.Elements("main").Elements("beta").Elements("epsilon").Select(x => x.Value).ToList() will resolve IEnumerable error. NOTE: the .ToList() call. Or instantiate as "IEnumerable<string> values =" instead and you don't need the .ToList() call.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.AppendText(quiz.Select(x => x.Value).Aggregate((s, s1) => s + s1));
```